# Hibernate prepared statement is replacing values with question mark

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2, websphere-6.1

We are using Hibernate 3 with WebSphere v6 and DB2. We are having strange issue with wrong SQL prepared statements issued by Hibernate and causing syntax issues.

Good query issued by Hibernate:

> SELECT * FROM rocc.Transaction t WHERE t.status_cd = 0 and
>   t.application_cd = ? order by coalesce(t.priority,0) fetch first 25
>   rows only

Same query issued by Hibernate incorrectly sometimes:

> SELECT * FROM rocc.Transaction t WHERE t.status_cd = ***?*** ***AND***
>   t.application_cd = ? ***ORDER BY COALESCE***(t.priority,***?***) ***FETCH*** first
>   ***?*** ***ROWS ONLY***

It is replacing values(zero) with question mark and changing font of the keywords to uppercase (it does not matter, but mentioning here). It also changed the number 25 in fetch clause with question mark.

What is causing with the wrong prepared statement issued by Hibernate sometimes?

Hibernate is calling WSJdbcPreparedStament.executeQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of the preparedStatement on JDBC, it substitutes the parameters on the query with ?, this also helps the database to construct a optimized access plan for your query. Hibernate is just automating this.

[Jdbc Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) or how we used to to before we have hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does JDBC change hard coded values with "?" and also hard coded fetch size to "?"

Comment: Yes, I guess that Hibernate generated the sql whith the ?, and in runtime, it uses the values you specified, adding the values to the PreparedStatement